# Merging multiple providers in Gradle. Difference between Provider.map vs project.provider

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have multiple `Provider`s in Gradle and would want to merge those into a single `Provider` config object while keeping lazy configuration in mind.

What's the difference between using cascading `Provider.flatMap` & `Provider.map`, versus creating a new `Provider` with `project.provider` & using `Provider.get()`?

Given multiple `Providers`:

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

val envProvider: Provider<String> = project.provider {
    val env: String? by project
    env ?: "sit"
}

val accountProvider: Provider<String> = project.provider {
    val account: String by project
    account
}

val regionProvider: Provider<String> = project.provider {
    val region: String? by project
    region ?: "us-east-1"
}
```

Merging to a single `Provider` using `Provider.flatMap` and `Provider.map`:

```kotlin
val configProvider: Provider<Config> = envProvider.flatMap { env ->
    accountProvider.flatMap { account ->
        regionProvider.map { region ->
            Config(
                env = env,
                account = account,
                region = region
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Merging to a single `Provider` using `project.provider` and `Provider.get`:

```kotlin
val configProvider: Provider<Config> = project.provider {
    Config(
        env = envProvider.get(),
        account = accountProvider.get(),
        region = regionProvider.get()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the docs for `get()`:

> Returns the value of this provider if it has a value present, otherwise throws {@code java.lang.IllegalStateException}.

From the docs for `map()` and `flatMap()`:

> The new provider will be live, so that each time it is queried, it queries this provider and applies the transformation to the result. Whenever this provider has no value, the new provider will also have no value and the transformation will not be called.

There are 2 differences using `Provider.get()` and `Provider.map` & `Provider.flatMap`

- When you have no value present, calling `get()` will throw an exception whereas calling `map()` or `flatMap()` will just not run the transformation you give. (The lambda block). In your case, if any of `envProvider`, `accountProvider` or `regionProvider` does not have a value present when you call `get`, then you will get an exception. On the other hand, it will just not execute the lambda you give for the `map` or `flatMap` but you will still get a provider with no value inside.
- `map` and `flatMap` returns a live `Provider` which means that even if the value is not present when you call, the transformation lambda you give to `map` or `flatMap` will be executed whenever there is a value present. With `get`, you only get an exception when there is no value.